# Unable to install polymer and all of it components

Tags: git, github, ssh, rsa, polymer

I am trying to install polymer and all its components as described here at the 
http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/tooling-strategy.html#git

```
mkdir polymer_local; cd polymer_local
git clone https://github.com/Polymer/tools.git
./tools/bin/pull-all.sh
```

I keep getting this error for all the packets:

```
Repo:  Polymer/PointerEvents.git
Folder:  components/PointerEvents
Operation:  clone
Reason:  Cloning into 'PointerEvents'...

Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Repo:  Polymer/topeka.git
Folder:  projects/topeka
Operation:  clone
Reason:  Cloning into 'topeka'...

Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 2):

It failed for me too, but I noticed that every time I was getting a different error. So I let it run in a loop and for a coffee:

```
while ! ./tools/bin/pull-all.sh; do date; echo sleep a bit ...; sleep 5; done
```

After half an hour it was still running (always failing), but the point of failure was always the same, the step of cloning `paper-scaffold`:

> ```
> FAILED REPOS
> Repo:  Polymer/paper-scaffold.git
> Folder:  components/paper-scaffold
> Operation:  clone
> Reason:  Cloning into 'paper-scaffold'...
>
> ERROR: Repository not found.
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.
>
> FAILED SYNC
> ```

After some digging around, I found it's trying to download a repo from GitHub that doesn't exist:

https://github.com/Polymer/paper-scaffold

To get around that, I edited the file `./tools/repo-configs/paper.json`, removed the line with `paper-scaffold`, and reran `./tools/bin/pull-all.sh`.

This way the script finally worked, but I don't know Polymer (looks nice though), and I don't know if you will have a usable setup. Good luck!

Comment: I tried what you suggested. But for some reason it still doesnt work. Were you able to pull down all the repos after making that change?

Comment: Yes. Btw, did you clone Polymer/tools today? You might get different results if you don't have the same version. The latest commit in mine is `f37e33443c606f93d1b5b384808c07da80368d1c`. With that version, and the change I wrote in my post, the script runs successfully.

Comment: commit f37e33443c606f93d1b5b384808c07da80368d1c. Looks to be the same. The thing is I the point of failure is a lot of packages and not just one.

Comment: For me it's just one. Did you try to start over, from step 1, creating a completely new `polymer_local` directory?

Comment: Yep. I think there is something funny going on with the key . I will try it on a new machine and let you know.

Comment: Here's something you can try: go to the `polymer_local/components` directory, and try to clone the failing repositories, for example `git clone https://github.com/Polymer/PointerEvents`. For topeka, do similarly in the `polymer_local/projects` dir.

Comment: Will do that. Thanks for the help

Comment: Fwiw, you should not be using `pull-all.sh` and/or any of the Git repositories unless you plan on committing changes to large numbers of repositories. `Bower` is dramatically more efficient for 99% of users.

Answer (score 1):

Have you [set up a public/private key pair](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) with GitHub? This problem sounds a lot like what happens when attempting to clone a GitHub repo using SSH without the key being set up: https://github.com/Polymer/tools/pull/27